# how to prevent/lock a function from returning until another separate async call has resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, race-condition

I'm working on route authentication, and am storing the authed status in a context so that other React components can check if a user is logged in. The relevant part of code is:

```js
const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useState(null)
const authed = () => !!loggedInUser

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch('/loggedInUser')
      .then(res => res.json())
    setLoggedInUser(response)
  }
  fetchData()
}, [])
```

The quick explanation of this code is, I need user data (such as id) in parts of code so I need to store the `loggedInUser` object. however, for simpler tasks such as checking if a user is logged in, I'm using the function `authed` to check if the `loggedInUser` variable contains an object (user is logged in) or is null.

To check if a user is logged in, I'm using passport.js and my `'/loggedInUser'` route looks like this:

```js
app.get('/loggedInUser', async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated())
    return null

  const { id, name } = await req.user
    .then(res => res.dataValues)

  return res.json({ id, name })
})
```

The problem is, code consuming this context and checking `authed()` is running before the `useEffect()` and `fetch()` are able to hit the GET route and use the API response to `setLoggedInUser(response)`. so use of `authed()` always returns false, even if the API response later sets `loggedInUser` to some object value where now `authed()` is true. obviously this is a race condition, but I'm not sure how to address it.

Is there an elegant solution where I can 'lock' `authed()` from returning a value until the useEffect() has fully 'set up' the state of `loggedInUser`?

One (awful) solution I'm envisioning may be something like:

```js
const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useState(null)
const isFinishedLoading = false // <--
function authed() {
  while (!isFinishedLoading) {} // a crude lock
  return !!loggedInUser
}

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch('/loggedInUser')
      .then(res => res.json())
    setLoggedInUser(response)
    
    isFinishedLoading = true // <--
  }
  fetchData()
}, [])
```

Is there a better way to 'lock' the function `authed()` until loading is complete?

---

Edit:

To clarify my usage of `authed()` for the comments, here is a trimmed down version of my `App.js`

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Router className="Router">
          <ProtectedRoute path="/" component={SubmittalTable} />
          <Login path="/login" />
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    </>
  )
}

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }){
  const { authed } = useContext(AuthContext)

  if (!authed()) // due to race condition, authed() is always false
    return (<Redirect from="" to="login" noThrow />)

  return (<Component {...rest} />)
}
```

Comment: Don't mix `await` and `.then`. They're trying to do similar things.

Comment: By "context" do you mean the React.Context? What do you pass to the provider? Did you tried to provide the `isLoggedIn` into the Provider?

Comment: This quite expansive, you're sending an http request everytime the page refreshes to check if the user is still logged in.  I reccomend checking out some articles regarding session management.

Comment: You're going to have trouble achieving "locking". Can you instead only render data via conditional statements once authentication has been validated and the data ha been loaded? Or redirect a user to a login page if they aren't authenticated and redirect back once auth has been confirmed? You can store authentication in centralized state and then redirect the user if the request comes back with a 401 from the api. Either way, you can't block render of the a component.

Comment: @AxisStarstreamer no I'm using for this as an AuthContext, similar to https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context. I am passing value={{isLoggedIn, authed}} to the provider, but this does not solve my race condition problem. `isLoggedIn` will share the same race-condition problem.

Comment: @Bergur I must be missing your point, because using react router I can avoid react re-renders upon route change. though refresh or clicking bookmarks etc would cause a re-render as you suggest, but not sure if this is that taxing? that said, I looked around and found advice to use cookies, local storage, or redux.. Redux seems like overkill. Do you think cookies/local storage would be better than React Context? Just trying to make sure I understand your intention

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky That's exactly what I am doing, see the Edit I made to the post. However the problem still stands that due to the race condition, `authed()` is always false.

Comment: Yeah refreshes, clicking links / new routes, means that content is not gonna be displayed until the react app sends a http request, the server checks the session or even database and returns the answer.

Comment: @Bergur okay let's assume I store a user's id in a cookie or in local storage. now instead of using `fetch()`, I'm using some other method `getIdFromCookie()` perhaps. I haven't done it before so correct me if I'm wrong, but that would likely also be async right? That doesn't solve my race condition.. however if it's synchronous it would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need `authed()` to be a function, and don't use `isLoggedIn` directly. Also I don't see where you are *setting* the Context value, but anyway ...

#### general suggestions

Generally: In React, try to think about

- *"what is the state of my app at any given moment"*,
- and not *"what should happen in which order"*.

In your case:

- "which page should be displayed right now, based on the state",
- instead of "redirect as soon as something happens".

The user *is* authorized or *is not* authorized to use your app at any given moment. That is a *state*, and you would store this state somewhere. Let's call this state `isAuthorized`.

#### different places to store state

1. You can store `isAuthorized` in the **Context**, as long as you know it is available when you need it. If the Context is *not* available at the moment when you want to know if the user is authorized (which seems to be the case in your app), then you *can not* use the Context to store `isAuthorized` (at least not alone).
2. You can **fetch** `isAuthorized` every time when you need it. Then `isAuthorized` is not available until the fetch responds. What is the state of your app right now ? It is `notReady` (probably). You can store the state `notReady` somewhere, e.g. again in the Context. (`notReady` will be always initially `true`, so you know the app is ready only if you explicitly say so.) The App might display a Spinner and do nothing else as long as it is `notReady`.
3. You can store `isAuthorized` in e.g. the **browser storages** (e.g. `sessionStorage`). They are available across page loads, so you don't have to fetch the state every time. The browser storages are supposed to be synchronous, but indeed I would treat them as being asynchronous, because things I have read about the browser storages are not inspiring confidence.

#### problem and solution

What you are trying to do is to store `isAuthorized` in the (1) Context AND (2) fetch it every time, so you have 2 states, which need to be **synchronized**. Anyway, you *do* need to fetch `isAuthorized` at least once in the beginning, without that, the app is not ready to be used. So you do need synchronization and a state (3) `notReady` (or `isReady`).

Synchronizing state is done with `useEffect` in React (or with 'dependencies'), e.g.:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsFinishedLoading( false );    // state (3) "app is ready"
  fetchData().then( response => {
    setLoggedInUser( response );    // state (2) "isAuthorized" from fetch
    setIsFinishedLoading( true );
  }).catch( error => {
    setLoggedInUser( null );
    setIsFinishedLoading( true );
  });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if( isFinishedLoading ){
    setIsAuthorized( !!response );      // state (1) "isAuthorized" in local state or Context
  }
  
}, [ isFinishedLoading, response ]);
```

#### "blocking"

You probably don't need it anyway, but:

Blocking code execution in that sense is not possible in Javascript. You would instead execute the code *at some other time*, e.g. using Promises. This again requires thinking in a slightly different way.

You can not do:

```
function authed(){
  blockExecutionBasedOnCondition
  return !!loggedInUser
}
```

But you can do:

```
function authed(){
  return !!loggedInUser;
}

function executeAuthed(){
  someConditionWithPromise.then( result => {
    authed();
  });
}
```